# Determine concurrency based on start and end date-time in epoch format using a mysql query

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table in the MySQL database, shown below, in which each line represents session data. Each session has a start- and stop date-time in epoch format and is connected to a specific server where a asset has been used.

```
 +--------------------------------------------+
 | Asset + Server   +  Start     + End        | 
 +--------------------------------------------+ 
 | 1     | 10.0.0.1 | 1397606535 | 1397606511 |
 | 1     | 10.0.0.2 | 1397606534 | 1397606311 |
 | 2     | 10.0.0.2 | 1397606533 | 1397606612 |
 | 1     | 10.0.0.1 | 1397606534 | 1397606511 |
 | 3     | 10.0.0.1 | 1397606531 | 1397609555 |
 | 1     | 10.0.0.3 | 1397606531 | 1397606511 |
 | 1     | 10.0.0.4 | 1397606525 | 1397606511 |
 | 4     | 10.0.0.3 | 1397606515 | 1397606411 |
 | 1     | 10.0.0.3 | 1397606135 | 1397606581 |
 | 6     | 10.0.0.1 | 1397606135 | 1397606511 |
 | 1     | 10.0.0.2 | 1397606525 | 1397606511 |
 | 5     | 10.0.0.1 | 1397606135 | 1397606511 |
 | 1     | 10.0.0.4 | 1397606535 | 1397606511 |
 +--------------------------------------------+
```

The main problem is that I'm trying to solve three problems:

1. What is the maximum amount of concurrent sessions?
2. What is the maximum amount of concurrent sessions per asset?
3. What is the maximum amount of concurrent sessions per server?

The three problems all have the same problem: how do i compare the start and end times while taking into account all the time in between?

Hopefully there is somebody who can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to take each row at a time and compare the dates with the others (except itself) to see how many times the interval overlaps and update your max number for each case when necesarry

```
DECLARE maxSessions INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT Asset,Server,Start,End FROM yourtable;
OPEN cur1;

read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO CurrAsset,CurrServer,CurrStart,CurrEnd;

    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable
    WHERE (Start >= CurrStart && Start <= CurrEnd) || (End >= CurrStart && End <= CurrEnd)
    INTO number;

    IF (number > maxSessions) THEN
       maxSessions = number;
    END IF;
END LOOP;

maxSessions--;  //Since one time it will be compared to itself
```

It can be adapted for the other 2 situations depending if you need to find out the max concurent times for each server/asset in particular or the max in general

Comment: Shouldn't there be a more graceful solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by fetching the entire data-set and processing it in code. I didn't find the cursor solution elegant and didn't give me the freedom i was looking for.